# Angular Tabulator table date not showing

Tags: angular, tabulator

I'm having trouble rendering a Tabulator table in an Angular component. I've defined the data (tableData) and columns (tableColumns) within the TypeScript file (test.component.ts) and attempted to initialize the Tabulator instance in the ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook. However, the table is not rendering as expected. I've checked for errors in the console, but there are no apparent issues.

I'd appreciate any guidance on what might be causing the problem or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve the issue.( i wanna show the table in test file test file is sub of form http://localhost:4200/pages/forms/test )

Thanks in advance for your help!

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import 'tabulator-tables';

declare var Tabulator: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-test',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
})
export class TestComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  exTable: any;
  // Removed the initialization of tableData and tableColumns here

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.exTable = new Tabulator('#ex-table-div', {
      height: 130,
      layout: 'fitColumns',
      movableColumns: true,
      // Data and columns will be passed via Angular property binding
    });
  }
}
```

and test.component.html code are

```
<h1>Test Page</h1>
<div id="ex-table-div"></div>

<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const tableData = [
      {
        id: '1',
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Smith',
        state: 'Ohio',
      },
      {
        id: '2',
        firstName: 'Jane',
        lastName: 'Doe',
        state: 'Iowa',
      },
      {
        id: '3',
        firstName: 'Bill',
        lastName: 'Great',
        state: 'Hawaii',
      },
      {
        id: '4',
        firstName: 'Ted',
        lastName: 'Adventure',
        state: 'Arizona',
      },
    ];

    const tableColumns = [
      { title: 'Id', field: 'id' },
      { title: 'First Name', field: 'firstName' },
      { title: 'Last Name', field: 'lastName' },
      { title: 'Location', field: 'state' },
    ];

    const exTable = new Tabulator('#ex-table-div', {
      height: 130,
      layout: 'fitColumns',
      movableColumns: true,
      data: tableData,
      columns: tableColumns,
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note you can just try step 2 and step 3 and implement the code, maybe it will work on local system, if not you can perform step 1 also. I have done all three steps to make the provided stackblitz work properly!

#### Step 1

You need to set `"noImplicitAny": false` in `tsconfig.json`.

You also need to install two things

#### Step 2

```
npm i tabulator-tables --save
```

#### Step 3

```
npm i @types/tabulator-tables --save-dev
```

After that you can import tabulator like shown in the below example, please let me know if any doubts.

ts

```
import {
  Component,
  Input,
  OnChanges,
  SimpleChanges,
  ViewChild,
  ElementRef,
} from '@angular/core';
import Tabulator from 'tabulator-tables';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tabulator',
  templateUrl: './tabulator.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tabulator.component.css'],
  standalone: true,
})
export class TabulatorComponent {
  @ViewChild('tabulator') tabulator!: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
  @Input() tableData: any[] = [];
  @Input() columnNames: any[] = [];
  @Input() height: string = '311px';
  // list properties you want to set per implementation here...

  tab = document.createElement('div');

  constructor() {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    this.drawTable();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    this.drawTable();
  }

  private drawTable(): void {
    if (this.tabulator.nativeElement) {
      new (Tabulator as any)(this.tabulator.nativeElement, {
        data: this.tableData,
        columns: this.columnNames,
        height: 130,
        layout: 'fitColumns',
        movableColumns: true,
      });
    }
  }
}
```

html

```
<div #tabulator></div>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-u438df?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=tsconfig.json,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Ftabulator%2Ftabulator.component.html,src%2Ftabulator%2Ftabulator.component.ts,src%2Fglobal_styles.css&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: Just curious: why do we need to use `as any` if you suggested to install  `@types/tabulator-tables`?

Comment: @yurzui You caught me :) we don't in stackblitz, but maybe it works in local system (the typing I mean), I haven't checked that